# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with GMSMapView

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an EXC_BAD_ACCESS who drive me crazy !! I'm trying to create a custom GMSCircle and when I'm assign  an instance of GMSMapView, it cause crash...

Anyone can help me, this is code:

```
...
@property (nonatomic, strong) GMSMapView *mapView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PGCRadarCircle *circle;
...
_mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
...
 _circle = [PGCRadarCircle radarWithPosition:[PGCLocationManager instance].currentLocation.coordinate
                                                map:_mapView
                                                 radius:500];
```

and

```
PGCRadarCircle.h

...
@property (nonatomic, strong) GMSMapView* map;
...

- (id)initWithPosition:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate map:(GMSMapView*)mapView radius:(CLLocationDistance)radius {
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self.numberOfPulse = 2;
        self.map = mapView;
        self.position = coordinate;
        self.radius = radius;
        self.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.5];
        self.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.9 alpha:0.5];
        self.strokeWidth = 1;
        self.running = false;
        self.waves = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.duration = 2;


        GMSCircle *wave = [GMSCircle circleWithPosition:self.position radius:0];
        wave.fillColor = _fillColor;
        wave.strokeColor = _strokeColor;
        wave.strokeWidth = _strokeWidth;
        wave.map = _map;  <--- EXC_BAD_ACCESS at this line

        [_waves addObject:wave];

        [self initWaves];
    }

    return self;
}
```

And a screenshot of stack:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7KLg.png)

[object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77Ybf.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using ARC?

Comment: Hi @Droppy, yes I'm using Xcode 7 with ARC.

Comment: OK, please post the complete crash log or stack trace.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

This issue can be because your coordinate is invalid, try put a check in it:

```
if (CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(self.position)) {
    wave.map = _map;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My EXC_BAD_ACCESS dissapeared after i set up circle radius before assigning map (GMSMapView) to GMSCircle. So try to put line `self.map = mapView;` lower in your code. I hope it will help you!